# How can I use a ModalBottomSheetLayout inside a scrollable Column?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

For some reason, adding a ModalBottomSheetLayout inside a scrollable column doesn't work. Moving it out of the column works, but then the button is misplaced. Is there a way to make a ModalBottomSheetLayout work inside a scrollable column? I couldn't find anything about this.

```
val modalBottomSheetScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
        sheetContent = {
            Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()) {
                Text("description")
            }
        },
    ) {
            TextButton(onClick = {
                modalBottomSheetScope.launch {
                    modalBottomSheetState.show()
                }
            }) {
                Text(text = "Read", color = Color.Black, style = TextStyle(textDecoration = TextDecoration.Underline))
            }
}
```

Adding this to a composable and inside a

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
        .fillMaxSize()
) { 

}
```

Will not allow for the bottomsheet to appear

Comment: Modals, like the ModalBottomSheetLayout or other dialogs, are meant to render outside of the view hierarchy. It sounds like this is not the component you should be attempting to use. Which attributes of the bottom sheet are you looking to use in your view?

Comment: Provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing what you are trying to achieve and what you have done so far.

Comment: @DanHarms, I'm attempting to show a sheet with some description when you press on a read button. This button is inside 1 big composable that holds other composables. 

When I debug, it the state gets properly modified but it doesn't display the sheet. Only when I take it outside scrollable column. Maybe it's possible to have the state outside so the can be shown when trying to modify it from within another composable.

All I want is to show the description in some sort of dialog

Comment: @Abhimanyu I added some more code to explain what I'm working with

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. You need to encapsulate said scrollable column with the modalbottomsheet to have it show up instead of making the modalbottomsheet the child of the column. Like this:

```
val modalBottomSheetScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
ModalBottomSheetLayout(
   sheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
   sheetContent = {
       Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()) {
           Text("description")
       }
   }
) {

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) { 

        TextButton(
            onClick = {
                modalBottomSheetScope.launch {
                    modalBottomSheetState.show()
            }
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Read", 
                color = Color.Black, 
                style = TextStyle(textDecoration = TextDecoration.Underline)
            )
        }
    }
}
```